# How to set time as from - to (4:00AM - 6:00AM) in HTML and save it to Database

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My application(which is in node.js environment) has a time scheduler. I want the user to input an array of their free times like, From 4:00AM to 6:00AM and 2:30PM to 4:30PM. Then i want to save that time periods in my MongoDb database. I have no clue how to achieve that and I've searched in a lot of places but maybe i'm not being able to get Google understand what i want.
UPDATE:
Am i doing it right?

This is in my mongoose schema:

```
times:[{
  day:String,
  timeOfDay:[{
    startTime: Number,
    endTime: Number
  }],
  date: Date
}]
```

Comment: I'm throwing in my hat with google, since I don't understand what you want either. Perhaps it would be clearer if you "showed us" what you expect to happen.

Comment: the user will pick a time period from a drop-down list(12:00AM-2:00PM), lets say, for Sunday. That information will be stored in the database like, User X is available at Sunday from 12:00AM to 2:00PM.

Comment: Nobody is going to write you a "how to" guide from end to end. You need to have some part of your process done and then ask a question about the part you do not understand. This may very well be several questions depending on what you know already. You probably need to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and the related links from that page. Somebody really should have pointed you there before now.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please at least see the updated question and tell me if i'm doing it right?